# Where Clause Gives Error:"The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT SchoolID
FROM   ParameterDetails
INNER JOIN
EstablishmentParameterValues AS v
ON v.ParameterID = ParameterDetailID
WHERE  NameResourceKey = 'NonTeachingStaffStartTime'
AND DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT (DATETIME, (CONVERT (NVARCHAR (20), CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()), 110) + ' ' + v.ParameterValue)), GETDATE()) <= 60
```

Above query gives the error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

When I use write

```
DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT (DATETIME, (CONVERT (NVARCHAR (20), CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()), 110) + ' ' + v.ParameterValue)), GETDATE()) <= 60
```

in Select Clause it does not give error, then why is it giving error in Where Clause..

V.ParameterValues table contains below kind of values:-

```
8:45
8:45
08:40:00
08:30:00
8:45
```

Comment: Can you say What is v.ParameterValue value?

Comment: If there are other values in `ParameterValue` which don't resemble times (maybe for something other than `NonTeachingStaffStartTime`) then you may be doomed until you split this into two separate queries. There's no guarantee on what order `WHERE` clause arguments are evaluated, and even if you e.g. moved part of this into a subquery, there's always [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) to inform you that that strategy won't protect you.

Comment: Did the below help, or are you still seeing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a mis-placed parenthesis... and the T-SQL message has nothing to do with your data.  Try changing: 
 
`CONVERT (NVARCHAR (20), CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()), 110)`, to 
 
`CONVERT (NVARCHAR (20), CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE(), 110))`, 
 
so that the `110` is inside that parenthesis.

If that doesn't fix your problem, you might try adding a `TOP 1` (like `SELECT TOP 1...`) to confirm that your basic code works (at least with the first row).

You also could check for values that are not converting properly with your current logic:  use the `ISDATE` function, which "[Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)":  
 
`WHERE ISDATE( CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),110) + ' ' + v.ParameterValue ) = 0`

Hope that helps...